# What are some alternatives to recursive search algorithms?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I am looking at alternatives to a deep search algorithm that I've been working on. My code is a bit too long to post here, but I've written a simplified version that captures the important aspects. First, I've created an object that I'll call 'BranchNode' that holds a few values as well as an array of other 'BranchNode' objects.

```
class BranchNode : IComparable<BranchNode>
{
    public BranchNode(int depth, int parentValue, Random rnd)
    {
        _nodeDelta = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
        _depth = depth + 1;
        leafValue = parentValue + _nodeDelta;

        if (depth < 10)
        {
            int children = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            branchNodes = new BranchNode[children];
            for (int i = 0; i < children; i++)
            {
                branchNodes[i] = new BranchNode(_depth, leafValue, rnd);
            }
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(BranchNode other)
    {
        return other.leafValue.CompareTo(this.leafValue);
    }


    private int _nodeDelta;
    public BranchNode[] branchNodes;
    private int _depth;
    public int leafValue;


}
```

In my actual program, I'm getting my data from elsewhere... but for this example, I'm just passing an instance of a Random object down the line that I'm using to generate values for each BranchNode... I'm also manually creating a depth of 10, whereas my actual data will have any number of generations.

As a quick explanation of my goals, _nodeDelta contains a value that is assigned to each BranchNode. Each instance also maintains a leafValue that is equal to current BranchNode's _nodeDelta summed with the _nodeDeltas of all of it's ancestors. I am trying to find the largest leafValue of a BranchNode with no children.

Currently, I am recursively transversing the heirarchy searching for BranchNodes whose child BranchNodes array is null (a.k.a: a 'childless' BranchNode), then comparing it's leafValue to that of the current highest leafValue. If it's larger, it becomes the benchmark and the search continues until it's looked at all BranchNodes.

I can post my recursive search algorithm if it'd help, but it's pretty standard, and is working fine. My issue is, as expected, that for larger heirarchies, my algorithm takes a long while to transverse the entier structure.

I was wondering if I had any other options that I could look into that may yield faster results... specificaly, I've been trying to wrap my head around linq, but I'm not even sure that it is built to do what I'm looking for, or if it'd be any faster. Are there other things that I should be looking into as well?

Comment: All recursive algorithms can be unwound and done using loops.

Comment: Although Linq may not be the right tool for the task in this case, you can [express recursion in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732281/expressing-recursion-in-linq) if you really want to.

Comment: is the data actually an object hierarchy or are  you getting the data as xml... or how are you getting the data?

Comment: The standard way to improve search times for queries over large data sets is to build another data structure called an "index" which *can* be searched rapidly. Google and Bing do not actually search the entire Internet in a few milliseconds; they search their indices of the entire Internet in a few milliseconds. My advice to you: build an index; search it.

Comment: Are you able to reference a BranchNode's parent from the object, or does it only maintain the child node array? I may have some thoughts if you can traverse both directions.

Comment: @jsobo The data is generated on the fly via an extrapolation of exisitng recursive data stored in a database. I do a query for the base data, then I 'grow' that data based upon a large number of extrapolation conditions. The whole point of it is to highlight potential 'outcomes' that we may need to be prepaired to target in the future.

Comment: @lthibodeaux I am looking at any method that may result in even slight speed gains. I have no problem passing a reference of a parent to it's children. It'd actually save me a handful of parameters, as i would then be able to reference the parent instead of passing a number of it's values.

Comment: If you can split up your tree in some meaningful way into N sub-trees, you could split that work up among different threads (on different cores) and then combine the result when all of them finish.

Comment: @Chronicide My question is essentially were I to have `BranchNode aNode`, is there a property of the object such that I can access its parent with the notation `aNode.ParentNode` or similar?

Comment: @lthibodeaux Currently, no... but I can easily pass a reference from the parent to the children nodes to give you aNode.ParentNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to look into an alternative data index structure: [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)

It always depends on the work you are doing with the data, but if you assign a unique ID on each element that stores the hierarchical form, and creating an index of what you store, your optimization will make much more sense than micro-optimizing parts of what you do.

Also, this also lends itself a very different paradigm in search algorithms, that uses no recursion, but in the cost of additional memory for the IDs and possibly the index.

Comment: While I used a handful of techniques from various answers, using a separate indexing seemed to be the most beneficial.

Comment: I'm glad this technique helped you, as it has helped me over the time. This particular way of indexing I am linking, has a special benefit: you can fetch a node with all the children (and children's children, etc) with only 1 low-cost query. It has higher write cost though, so it's to be used in a case where writing is sparser than reading

Answer (score 1):

If you must visit all leaf nodes, you cannot speed up the search: it is going to go through all nodes no matter what. A typical trick played to speed up a search on trees is organizing them in some special way that simplifies the search of the tree. For example, by building a binary search tree, you make your search `O(Log(N))`. You could also store some helpful values in the non-leaf nodes from which you could later construct the answer to your search query.

For example, you could decide to store the _bestLeaf "pointing" to the leaf with the highest _nodeDelta of all leaves under the current subtree. If you do that, your search would become an `O(1)` lookup. Your inserts and removals would become more expensive, however, because you would need to update up to `Log-b(N)` items on the way back to root with the new `_bestLeaf` (`b` is the branching factor of your tree).

Comment: In the past, our branching factor has reached an avarage nearly 25, so I think that having to add such a significant amount of overhead to the generation would counteract a great deal of the gain. The overall cost will be measured in the time to 'grow' our data along with the time it takes to search. I will try my hand at this method, just to see how it compares overall. I'll get back once I've done some reading and tried a few benchmarks.

Comment: @Chronicide Big branching factor is actually good: it means fewer updates along the path to the root would be needed.

Comment: which just goes to show that I'll have try to gain a better understanding of your answer before I make any further comments. I'm fairly certain that building a binary tree isn't possible with the nature of my data, I hadn't thought about 'searching' while I was growing my data... (at least, I think that is what you were suggesting... I have to admit that most of your answer is still a bit beyond me.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing you should think about is maybe going away from the N-Tree and going to as Binary Search tree.

This means that all nodes have only 2 children, a greater child, and a lesser child.

From there, I would say look into balancing your search tree with something like a Red-Black tree or AVL. That way, searching your tree is O(log n).

Here are some links to get you started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree

Now, if you are dead set on having each node able to have N child nodes, here are some things you should thing about:

1. Think about ordering your child nodes so that you can quickly determine which has the highest leaf number.  that way, when you enter a new node, you can check one child node and quickly determine if it is worth recursively checking it's children.
2. Think about ways that you can quickly eliminate as many nodes as you possibly can from the search or break the recursive calls as early as you can.  With the binary search tree, you can easily find the largest leaf node by always only looking at the greater child.  this could eliminate `N-log(n)` children if the tree is balanced.
3. Think about inserting and deleting nodes.  If you spend more time here, you could save a lot more time later

Answer (score 0):

As others mention, a different data structure might be what you want.

If you need to keep the data structure the same, the recursion can be unwound into loops. While this approach will probably be a little bit faster, it's not going to be orders of magnitude faster, but might take up less memory.