# LINQ query through several object "layers" in an IList?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Category>` where `Category` is:

```
public class Category {
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } // this holds sub-categories
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Since `Categories` is itself another `List<Category>` it could contain sub-categories, and those sub-categories could contain sub-categories, and so forth...

I know I can query past the first "layer" like so:

```
Categories.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I effectively query for a specific `Category` by `Id`, perhaps 3,4, or 5 layers deep in the object tree (there are at most 3, but for future reference I'd like to know)?

**Edit**

In addition, how could I get the entire object tree, all the way up to the top level `Category`, if I only had an `Id` of a sub-category 3 layers deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will recursively traverse categories until category matching passed id will be found (if any). Full path to found category will be returned (i.e. like breadcrumbs menu does):

```
static IEnumerable<Category> GetById(IEnumerable<Category> categories, string id)
{
    if (categories == null || !categories.Any())
        yield break;

    Category result = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (result != null)
    {
        yield return result;
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        var subCategories = GetById(category.Categories, id);
        if (subCategories.Any()) // we have found the category
        {
            yield return category; // return current category first

            foreach (var subCategory in subCategories)                    
                yield return subCategory;                   

            yield break; // don't search in other categories
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Category> result = GetById(categories, id);
// Food > Beer > Kilkenny
string breadcrumbs = String.Join(" > ", result.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray());
```

You can convert this method to extension if you wish.

Comment: If you are only really expecting one (or zero) result you should use SingleOrDefault() you are ignoring duplicates and it would seem they are either an error or should be part of the result

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method like the following to flatten `Category` as an `IEnumerable<Category>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> Flatten(this Category category)
{
    if (category.Categories != null)
    {
        foreach (var sub in category.Categories)
        {
            foreach (var subSub in sub.Flatten())
                yield return subSub;
        }
    }
    yield return category;
}
```

Then you use Linq on the `IEnumerable<Category>` as you like:

```
var filtered = categoryList.SelectMany(x => x.Flatten())
                           .Where(x => x.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to recurse through the `Categories` if you had an indeterminate level of nesting, and even if you had a fixed level of nesting, for any level of nesting more than 2-3 levels down, it would be worth recursing.

Linq doesn't really have a way of expressing recursion, although this post talks about using Linq2Xml features to achieve it: [Expressing recursion in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732281/expressing-recursion-in-linq)

If you are able to modify the class itself, you could implement a `GetChildById`-style method to recursively scan through the child `Categories`.